# parsing xml value element by xpath

Tags: php, xml, xpath

this is xml

```
<yml_catalog date="2016-03-23 13:33">
    <categories>
        <category id="1" parentId="0">Test</category>
        <category id="131" parentId="1">Test 1</category>
        <category id="19" parentId="1">Test 2</category>
        <category id="20" parentId="1">Test 3</category>
        <category id="21" parentId="1">Test 4</category>
        <category id="22" parentId="1">Test 5</category>
```

and I get category id by xpath

`var_dump($xmlObject->xpath("//yml_catalog/shop/categories/category[@id='22']"));die;`

and I get this output:

```
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  class SimpleXMLElement#94 (1) {
    public $@attributes =>
    array(2) {
      'id' =>
      string(2) "22"
      'parentId' =>
      string(1) "1"
    }
  }
}
```

Question: How to get `Text 5` in element, using method xpath?

Comment: If you only like to get the text content from category element with attribute id=22 add `/.`  or `/text()` to your xpath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using XPath expression in general, you can either use `/text()` to get text node that is child of current context element, or wrap the entire XPath with `string()` function to convert the first returned element to `string` :

```
//yml_catalog/shop/categories/category[@id='22']/text()
string(//yml_catalog/shop/categories/category[@id='22'])
```

---

Using `SimpleXML` specifically, you can just cast the element to `string` like so :

```
var_dump((string)$xmlObject->xpath("//yml_catalog/shop/categories/category[@id='22']")[0]);
```

**Demo :** https://eval.in/541310

**Output :** `string(6) "Test 5"`